# DVSYS object(package body) invalid

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am using oracle 12c [oracle database vault](https://www.oracle.com/database/database-vault/index.html) with `opt=false` but still having invalid object for `dvsys` user.

I have run

- `catalog.sql`
- `catproc.sql`
- `utlrp.sql`

but still not get validate this object.

Comment: You should read [ask]; What error do you get? "INVALID" can be so many things.

Comment: How have you tried to validate your package body? Have you tried to connect  [`AS SYSDBA`](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/database/oracle/connect_as_sys_without_password)? I guess so, but you're not telling us what you tried ***precisely***.

Comment: i have tried by sysdba also.alter packackage dvsys.dbms_maclos compile body.it will hive error like compilation error

Comment: and in my environment we  not using datavault.still giving invalid objects

Comment: WHAT error ? Give us the results of `select * from dba_errors`

Comment: PLS-00905: object DVSYS.DV$CODE is invalid

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no errors, but object invalidated because one of its reference changed. It sometimes happens.

2 things you may try:

1. just call its description.

   ```
   SQL> desc DVSYS.DV$CODE
   ```
2. use `dbms_utility` to  compile the schema where some objects are invalid (you may need to [connect as `sysdba`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12015.htm)):

   ```
   SQL> begin dbms_utility.compile_schema('DVSYS', FAlSE); end;   
   /
   ```

Comment: i have tried this solution but still macols invakid

Comment: dbms_macutl,dbms_macadm,dbms_macsec,dbms_macols_session, package body are still invalid

Comment: alter package DVSYS.DBMS_MACUTL compile body;

Warning: Package Body altered with compilation errors.

SQL> show error
Errors for PACKAGE BODY DVSYS.DBMS_MACUTL:

Comment: -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
278/13   PL/SQL: Item ignored
278/13   PLS-00905: object DVSYS.DV$CODE is invalid
288/9    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
290/14   PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
294/9    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
294/16   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
         incomplete or malformed

Comment: 298/10   PL/SQL: Item ignored
298/10   PLS-00905: object DVSYS.DV$CODE is invalid
308/9    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
309/14   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
         incomplete or malformed

310/9    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
314/9    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
314/16   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
         incomplete or malformed

Comment: @pramod, at this point we see you're missing an object or table... You'd better retry your installation ***connected `as sysdba`***... Or contact Oracle support.